# sqlite DATETIME formatting and ordering, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, select, sql-order-by, datetime-format

I have a number of "DATETIME's" for the following form e.x.:

```
2014-01-15T19:30:00-0800
```

I am successfully inserting them into an sqlite table that I created with the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE STUFF(id unique,date_time DATETIME)
```

When I query using the statement below I get all the dates I inserted back but not ordered.

```
SELECT * FROM STUFF ORDER BY DATETIME(date_time) DESC;
```

I'm guessing this is a formatting issue but I'm not sure. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a [date format supported by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html);
a time zone indicator must have the form `±HH:MM`:

```
> SELECT DATETIME('2014-01-15T19:30:00-0800');

> SELECT DATETIME('2014-01-15T19:30:00-08:00');
2014-01-16 03:30:00
```

Comment: Any chance you can show me how to get it in the right format using javascript? It seems like no matter what I do it it it get's returned as type "string".

Comment: In SQLite, timestamps *are* strings.